# Can I publish my invention here on SE as in the public domain?

Tags: discussion

I am afraid most if not all of my inventions will never be realized. I would rather give away life saving inventions then let them die with me.

Is this a good place to put my invention for the world to have and also to get feed back?

Comment: You might want to look at this question and its answers: https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/5341/how-can-i-provably-put-something-in-the-public-domain-so-that-someone-else-can-n/5343#5343

Answer (score 5):

It is not really what this site if for. I'm afraid it will probably be deemed off topic. [This question](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/5341/how-can-i-provably-put-something-in-the-public-domain-so-that-someone-else-can-n/5343#5343) asks for sites that allow public disclosure of patentable ideas to preclude others from stealing the inventions and obtaining patents. In particular http://firsttodisclose.org seems like a good possibility.

Comment: Firsttodisclose.org seems to have been hijacked by a law firm.

Comment: Search engines can't find the site.  There are some repos that look relevant.  Seems to have been untouched for about 8 years. 
 https://legal-engineering.mit.edu/FirstToDisclose, https://github.com/FirstToDisclose/firsttodisclose.net,